# Android: inserting sqlite record with AUTOINCREMENT column

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an sqlite database on android created like this:

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE criterion ('_id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, active text, important text, sort int, summary text, user text, category_id int, entrytype int);
```

The only way I can insert a record into this table is by specifying a value for **_id** which I want to auto-increment. This is the only way I can get the insert working:

```
recid = totalrecs + 1;
String q = "insert into criterion (_id, active, important, sort, summary, user, category_id, entrytype) values (" + recid + ", \"1\", \"0\", 99, \"foobar\", \"1\", 99, 0)";
Log.d (TAG, "query:" + q);
mDb.execSQL (q);
```

If I leave the _id column out and don't specify a value for _id, I get an error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: criterion._id may not be NULL: insert into criterion(active, important, sort, summary, user, category_id, entrytype) values ("1", "0", 99, "foobar", "1", 99, 0)
```

How do I arrange the query (or schema) so Android will take care of incrementing the **_id** column?

**Update/fixed 2 lines above (removed NOT NULL, removed _id from query):**

```
CREATE TABLE criterion ('_id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, active text, important text, sort int, summary text, user text, category_id int, entrytype int);

String q = "insert into criterion (active, important, sort, summary, user, category_id, entrytype) values (\"1\", \"0\", 99, \"foobar\", \"1\", 99, 0)";
```

Comment: eek you should really consider using the `SQLiteDatabase` `insert` method rather than creating these raw string statements

Comment: Agreed. It's unwieldy code however the circumstances didn't allow for an alternative method. Also, anyone following this thread should be forewarned that unsanitized/unescaped user input in an SQL insert statement, as shown above, is cause for egregious 'eek'.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Remove the NOT NULL from the schema and you're golden.

Clarifying:
Specifying NOT NULL on an auto-increment column makes it so the auto-increment doesn't function.  The NOT NULL is what is making it so you have to specify the _id.

Once you remove it, and don't include the _id in the insert statement, SQL will receive the _id as NULL and automatically handle setting the _id for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've run into a similar issue and your solution helped me to move on. However, I must admit that removing NOT NULL is surprisingly unobvious in such a case.