# Registration form not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using this code for registering users, but it is not working. It always echos "Registration failed." I tried many times but nothing works

```
if(isset($_POST['sub']))
{
    $uname = $_POST['uname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass_hash = PassHash::hash($_POST['pass']);

    $sq="SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$uname'";
    //echo $sq;
    $re=mysqli_query($link,$sq);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($re)>0)
    {
        echo "Username  already taken !";
    }
    else
    {
        $SQ = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email'";
        //echo $SQ;
        $res=mysqli_query($link,$SQ);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($res)>0)
        {
            echo "Email already taken !";
        }
        else
        {
            $SQL = "INSERT INTO user(username,email,password) VALUES('$uname','$email','$pass_hash')";
            //echo $SQL;
            $result = mysqli_query($link,$SQL);
            if(!$result)
            {
                echo "Registration failed !";
            }
            else
            {
                echo"register done";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

below is table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) default '0',
  `sdate` date NOT NULL,
  `s_type` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: What does `echo mysqli_error($link)` print?

Comment: Other than the glaring SQL injection vulnerability being a problem, what is the actual result from the query?  Are there any errors from the database?  If I were to guess based on nothing more than the query provided I'd perhaps suggest wrapping `user` in back-ticks as it may be a reserved word in MySQL.  (It's generally safest to wrap other object identifiers the same way.)

Comment: @andrewsi it shows a blank page

Comment: How about `$result = mysqli_query($link,$SQL) or die (mysqli_error($link));` ?

Comment: what is the size of your password field in the user table and what is the length of the hash created by PassHash::hash?

Comment: in your quesiton you said it always echoes registration fails. Is the page blank or does it say registration failed?

Comment: sorry my fault..if i use     $result = mysqli_query($link,$SQL) or die (mysqli_error($link));       then it shows blank and if echo i it shows nothing

Comment: anyone know whats the problem ?

Comment: i added user details manually and it also not echo's **Username  already taken**  if the username and email already exists

Comment: Hey..I removed        mysqli_close();      from config file and now register code is working.Why mysqli_close(); is crating problem ?

Comment: To that what Vedran answered: remove NOT_NULL from id, sdate, s_type and amount columns. Also read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070252/android-inserting-sqlite-record-with-autoincrement-column#8070278

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bunch of `not null` fields in your table, but you're not assigning them any values, so your `insert` query fails.